# How to sync local code changes to github?

Tags: git, github

I have made my very first repository on GitHub: https://github.com/Konstantinusz/picstate

I simply followed this help page: https://help.github.com/articles/adding-an-existing-project-to-github-using-the-command-line/

And the Ruby source file appeared on GitHub. But after then I discovered an error in the source, so I would like to remove or comment out a line. Of course I made the changes in my local Ruby source file. My question is how can I sync the GitHub repository to contain the changes? When I issue the command:

```
git push
```

I get only a message: "Everything up-to-date"
However the local Ruby file and the source on GitHub are different.

Comment: Did you `git commit` any changes? You have to commit to your local repository before you can push it elsewhere.

Comment: What does `git status` return?

Comment: On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
nothing to commit, working directory clean

Comment: Seems relevant: http://xkcd.com/1597/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pobably you didn't commit the changes to your local repository.

```
git add your_file.rb
git commit -m "Commit message"
```

Comment: I typed:
`git add picstate.rb`

Comment: @Konstantin you have to both `add` and `commit` your changes before you can `push` it to GitHub.

Comment: yes, I typed: `git add picstate.rb` | `git commit -m "edited" `
----------------------------------
[master 3178ece] require 'pry' removed
 1 file changed, 1 deletion(-)
---------------------------------
`git push`
Counting objects: 3, done.
Delta compression using up to 2 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (2/2), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 287 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 1), reused 0 (delta 0)
To https://github.com/Konstantinusz/picstate
   6a42995..3178ece  master -> master

Comment: But content on github didn't change.

Comment: Thx, now it worked. Changes were synced, maybe I had to refresh the browser.